# PHP timestamp output format

Tags: php, html

Here is the attribute "DATUM" in my database
[image]
Here is the code in the php file

[image]

And here is the output

[image]

Now i want a other format. Like *- geschrieben von Hans am 30.01.2015 um 12 Uhr -*. How can i change the format of the timestamp output?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// $row['DATUM'] contains "2015-01-30 12:09:53";

$d = date_create($row['DATUM']);
print_r($d->format('jS M, Y H:i A'));
```

Sample output: 30th Jan, 2015 12:09 PM

More information on formats: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now is here: `print_r($d->format('j.m.Y H:i'));` But i want a output with some word between the date and the time. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display it in German then take a look at functions [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

Be warned that you might get slightly different results on different operating systems. The differences are minor though.
Also, the values for the `$locale` parameter of `setlocale()` are not consistent across all the OSes (Windows is the outsider).

This is not an impediment if you use similar OSes on the development and production machines. It was a small annoyance for me because I was developing on Windows and the production machines ran Linux (Fedora and Ubuntu).